# Extract nested inline Jade elements from a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

Inside of a Jade file, I have a JavaScript string like `- var example = "Hello #[a(href='#') World]"`, which I pass to a paragraph element like `p=example`.

This undesirably outputs an HTML paragraph element like `<p>Hello #[a(href='#') World]</p>`.

The output I am looking for is `<p>Hello <a href='#'>World</a></p>`

**Is there any trick around this? Am I going about this poorly?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I just found this article in the Jade documents on [escaping](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#escaping). Which gives a similar example (I edited it to match my example):

The updated JavaScript string is `- var example = "Hello <a href='#'>World</a>"`

`p=example` => `<p>Hello &lt;a href='#'&gt;World&lt;/a&gt;</p>`

`p!=example` => `<p>Hello <a href='#'>World</a></p>`

I'm going to test this out now.

**EDIT2:**

It works! Now to do a lot of editing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMdPdX

```js
 - var example = "Hello <a(href='#')>World<a/>"
p!{example}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!